# Entity Framework 4.1 Want the Model to have non-null validatiom but dont want the database to be not null

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

This might sound like a weird request but how do I enforce validation at the model level using DataAnnotations that aren't enforced at the data store level when using EF 4.1 Code First.

Comment: Surely your database should reflect your EF?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that if you want to generate database from your mapping. Data annotation on mapped class defines mapping to database. If you need somewhere in UI to enforce different rules you need separate class for that - for example View model in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Hi Ladislav, that's what i was thinking. So I'm creating a ViewModel. The trouble is that this ViewModel needs to contain a collection of the same Person object that contains the Data Validation. This means that my ViewModel Person object has to derive from the Person object but add in the the Validation.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you but your view model should not derive from entity.